# Python Script to SSH

Tags: python, shell, ssh

I am a beginner trying to do SSH writing a basic code, I have tried everything not able to debug this , My code is as follows :

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
print ("1")
ssh.connect('196.5.5.6', username='abc', password='abc')
print ("2")
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('show version')
print ("3")
output= stdout.readlines()
print ("4")
print(output)
```

Output I get is 1
2
3


At 4 it get's stuck somewhere , there is problem that I am not able to fetch the data , Please help anyone. Code just hangs at the output step. Everywhere the solution is totally same.

Comment: Shouldn't you be printing stdout.readlines() ?

Comment: The values goes into the output , Then I am printing output

Comment: Still it will hang up , just tried that

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do `readlines(`) on `stdin`. You can print it directly. `readlines()` expect a file to be opened and read from the file. Whereas `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` are not files, rather a block of strings ( or string buffer used in paramiko channel). If you check the type of `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr`, you will find `<class 'paramiko.channel.ChannelFile'>`, which are not exactly files, but are file like objects created to store the buffers in paramiko channel.

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
print 1
ssh.connect('196.5.5.6', username='abc', password='abc')
print 2
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('show version')
print 3
output= stdin
print 4
print(output)
print '---', stdout
print '---==', stderr
```

Comment: yes Pabitra I got that but this will return you something like this :

Comment: <paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko channel window something.............>

Comment: Yes that is paramiko channelfile, not an actual file. So, on the same, you can't use `readlines()` method.

Comment: How should i do it then as even the paramiko suggest to do the same thing.

Comment: Did you try the above solution? instead of doing `output= stdout.readlines()`, do `output= stdout`. Then, In my case, I can see the output. Check the same. I guess that should work at your end as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should enter commands try this

```
import paramiko 
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
print ("1")
ssh.connect('ip', username='user', password='pass')
print ("2")
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('show version')
print ("3")
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("ls /")
print stdout.readlines()
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Unfortunately there is problem with stdout.readlines() only ! , its still hangs the code

Comment: really? ill screen shot my output

Comment: try reinstalling python

Comment: Man, I have done it all , it just wont move ahead of the readline comment !

Comment: what is it connecting to?

Comment: I have a router I am working with, You tried with localhost right ? ..Paste the exact code here , I tried using localhost here There is no hanging up of code but stdout not returning anything, Give me ur code I will try it out

Comment: Works with local host not able to work on machine i mean router